# I want to add delay to my menu when pictures are changing. How is it possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

These are my HTML and jQuery codes. When nav and its children become hover, I would like to change the pictures of menu with delay. Can you guide me ?

```
<!-- header --

<nav class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="" data-index="1">
        Home
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="" data-index="2">
        About Us
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="" data-index="3">
        Services
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="" data-index="4">
        Shop
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="" data-index="5">
        Our Teams
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="" data-index="6">
        Blog
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="" data-index="7">
        Contact Us
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

These are my HTML and jQuery codes. When nav and its children become hover, I would like to change the pictures of menu with delay. Can you guide me ?

```
jQuery

  // menu toggler click event

  $(".menu-toggler").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("menu-toggler-close");
    $(".nav").fadeToggle();
  });
  $(".nav").click(function() {
    $(".menu-toggler").removeClass("menu-toggler-close");
    $(".nav").fadeOut();
  });
  $(".nav > ul").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });

  $(".nav > ul > li > a").hover(
    function() {
      var dataIndex = $(this).data("index");

      $(".nav").css(
        "background",
        "url('images/nav" + dataIndex + ".webp') center center / cover"
      );
    },
    function() {
      $(".nav").css("background", "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)");
    },
```

Comment: Share your *code* instead of *picture* of it *!*

Comment: Thanks for your response Pedram. I am new on Stackoverflow.com . It takes time till I become professional. OK.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) | You can **edit** your question, and add your jQ or JavaScript code, instead of that picture.

Comment: Does anyone have an answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setTimeout()` method to delay your code.

```js
setTimeout(function()
{
    $(".nav").css(
        "background",
        "url('images/nav" + dataIndex + ".webp') center center / cover"
    );
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Does anyone have an answer?